# Extract values from string divided by pipes not in regular order

Tags: php, function, pipe, extract

I've a part of an xml that i'm importing that is not in a regular order. It could be for example:

> 87||1|#88||2|#89||2|50198#41||1|#3||1|117#20|||#6|20|1|#24|||78#145|5||#36|||90#37|||96#29|||67#26|||#27|||#25|||

I create a function like this:
`function caratteristiche1($title) {
    $title=substr($title,11,1); 
    return $title;
}`

to receive the value of #88 but sometimes #88 is not in that position, and other times #88 is not present.
I would like to use a function that will search for #88 and give as result the value present after the 2 subseguent pipes.

What can i do?
Thank you so much!

Comment: So in this example the expected output is `2`? And what if #88 is not present?

Answer (score 0):

If the distance between the #88 and the two pipes is identical in all cases, you can use a Regular Expression with a "positive lookbehind assertion", see http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php

If not, you probably need to use plain PHP to locate the #88, then take the remaining substring from there on and search for the two pipes.

EDIT after your answer of "NO":
In this case, I wouldn't do it with RegEx.
Try something like that (might not be 100% accurate syntax):

```
$pos88 = strpos('#88', $string);
newStr = substr($string, $pos88);
$posPipes = strpos('||', $newStr);
// ... and so forth ...
```

Comment: No, sometimes between the two pipes (#88|*|[1,9]) there might be something written. Other times (#88||[1.9]|) can not be present. Thanks a lot for your help!